# Java Generic Types Mismatch Error

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

I have a class with a constructor signature as follows:

```
public class MyClass <U>{
    public <T> MyClass(Set<T> data, Function<T,U> func)...
}
```

That's fine. But I want to overload the constructor, for the case that if you don't provide Function `func`, it will just use `(item)->{return item;}`. I've written another constructor that looks like this:

```
public <T> MyClass(Set<T> data){
    this(
      data,
      (item)->{return item;}
    );
}
```

This is causing a type mismatch error, because the function I'm providing as an argument to my constructor takes a value of type `T`, and returns that same value, which should be a `U`. I don't understand why the algebraic type system doesn't see that in this case U and T are the same and that's ok?

Comment: You don’t need a clumsy syntax like `(item)->{return item;}`, just write `item -> item`. Or, well, `Function.identity()`…

Comment: Thanks @Holger, I switched to using `Function.identity()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system has to assume that T and U are two different types, since you gave them two different names. But you can just remove the additional generic type from your second ctor like that:

```
public class MyClass <U>{
    public <T> MyClass(Set<T> data, Function<T,U> func) {...}
    public MyClass(Set<U> data){
        this(
          data,
          (item)->{return item;}
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I am an idiot. Oops. I assumed the Type Mismatch was between U and T, not realising that I had in effect made two different Ts in different scopes. That sorted it perfectly, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to create an instance of your class using the second constructor :

```
Set<Integer> ints = new HashSet<>();
MyClass<String> myobj = new <Integer> MyClass (ints);
```

your first constructor would expect a `Set<Integer>` and a `Function<Integer,String>` parameters, but your second constructor would try to pass to it a `Function<Integer,Integer>`. That's the reason your code doesn't pass compilation.

When you define generic classes and methods, they must be valid for any combination of types that can substitute their type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared two distinct types T and U, compiler reasonably thinks they are different. If they are the same, do not declare T and use only U:

```
public MyClass(Set<U> data){
    this(
      data,
      (item)->{return item;}
    );
}
```